# How found if four points contain a generic P point

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, geometry, point

I have a set of points (10000 - 15000). For each point, I know the coordinates (X,Y). For any generic P point I want to determine the four points that shape a quadrilateral around P, like in  figure
[[image: figure 1]]

I tried to calculate the distance between P and the other points and pick up the nearest ones, but this method doesn't work everytime because the points haven't a regular dislocation. It happens something like in figure below
[[image: figure 2]]

Comment: You need to tell us more about what counts as "the four points that shape a quadrilateral around P". For example, in your second picture, what's wrong with choosing the same bottom two points you have, the 'd2' point, and the same top-left point you have? Those four make "a quadrilateral around P"...

Answer (score 0):

Build [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Applications) of point set.

Make some data structure to quickly find a triangle for given point. I think that [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) with bounding rectangles for every triangle is a good choice.

When triangle is found, search for its neighbors to build the best quadrilateral